# Styling Sections and Bulleted Lists via Google Docs API

Tags: python, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to automate some document creation in Google Docs via a Python script, and I think I haven't quite wrapped my head around how the Google Docs API's `batchUpdate()` method works.

I have my own JSON-based config file that my script reads in and generates some content in a corresponding Google Doc document. I'm essentially iterating over a dictionary of various sections destined for the document. My hope is to have a document structure like the following:

-- snip --

### Section A

- placeholder

### Section B

- placeholder

etc...

-- snip --

I have no issues creating some section headers (`HEADING_2`s), and I've been doing so in reverse order because it seems easier:

```
requests = []
curr_item = {}

for section in reversed(user_config["sections"]):
  # section text
  curr_item = {"insertText": {"location": {"index": 1}, "text": "{section_name}\n".format(section_name=i["name"])}}
  requests.append(curr_item)
  
  # section formatting (as an H2)
  curr_item = {"updateParagraphStyle": {"range": {"startIndex": 1, "endIndex": len(i["name"])}, "paragraphStyle": {"namedStyleType": "HEADING_2", "fields": "namedStyleType,spaceAbove,spaceBelow"}}
  requests.append(curr_item)

result = svc.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=doc_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

So far, so good

But adding placeholder bulleted lists into the mix has been causing me problems:

```
requests = []
curr_item = {}

bullet_placeholder = "placeholder"

for section in reversed(user_config["sections"]):
  # section text
  curr_item = {"insertText": {"location": {"index": 1}, "text": "{section_name}\n".format(section_name=i["name"])}}
  requests.append(curr_item)
  
  # section formatting (as an H2)
  curr_item = {"updateParagraphStyle": {"range": {"startIndex": 1, "endIndex": len(i["name"])}, "paragraphStyle": {"namedStyleType": "HEADING_2", "fields": "namedStyleType,spaceAbove,spaceBelow"}}
  requests.append(curr_item)

  # placeholder list
  curr_item = {"insertText": {"location": {"index": len(i["name"]) + 2}, "text": "placeholder"}, "createParagraphBullets": { "range": { "startIndex": len(i["name"]) + 2, "endIndex": len(bullet_placeholder) + 2 }, "bulletPreset": "BULLET_ARROW_DIAMOND_DISC" } }
  requests.append(curr_item)

result = svc.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=doc_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

This results in the following error response:

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/foo-document-id:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'requests[2]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'
Invalid value at 'requests[5]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'
Invalid value at 'requests[8]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'
Invalid value at 'requests[11]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'
Invalid value at 'requests[14]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'
Invalid value at 'requests[17]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'
Invalid value at 'requests[20]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'requests[2]', 'description': "Invalid value at 'requests[2]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'"}, {'field': 'requests[5]', 'description': "Invalid value at 'requests[5]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'"}, {'field': 'requests[8]', 'description': "Invalid value at 'requests[8]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'"}, {'field': 'requests[11]', 'description': "Invalid value at 'requests[11]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'"}, {'field': 'requests[14]', 'description': "Invalid value at 'requests[14]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'"}, {'field': 'requests[17]', 'description': "Invalid value at 'requests[17]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'"}, {'field': 'requests[20]', 'description': "Invalid value at 'requests[20]' (oneof), oneof field 'request' is already set. Cannot set 'createParagraphBullets'"}]}]">
```

I've tried a few other approaches, like keeping track of the index based on the length of all text written up to a given point in time, calling batch update at the end of each iteration of the `for` loop but all to no avail.

I'd be interested to know what I'm missing or misunderstanding about the APIs for [inserting](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/move-text) + [formatting](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/format-text) text and [creating lists](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I saw your showing request body from your script, I thought of the following modification points:

#### Modification points:

- In your script, for example, at `curr_item = {"updateParagraphStyle": {"range": {"startIndex": 1, "endIndex": len(i["name"])}, "paragraphStyle": {"namedStyleType": "HEADING_2", "fields": "namedStyleType,spaceAbove,spaceBelow"}}`, `}` is required to be added. So I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script for replicating your issue.
- About your script of `So far, so good`, I think that `curr_item = {"updateParagraphStyle": {"range": {"startIndex": 1, "endIndex": len(i["name"])}, "paragraphStyle": {"namedStyleType": "HEADING_2", "fields": "namedStyleType,spaceAbove,spaceBelow"}}` is required to be modified.
- `"fields": "namedStyleType,spaceAbove,spaceBelow",` is moved to out side of `paragraphStyle`.
- `insertText` and `createParagraphBullets` are required to be separated for each request.
- If you want to achieve the following situation, I thought that the paragraph style of `- placeholder` is required to be also set.

  ### Section A

  - placeholder

  ### Section B

  - placeholder

  etc...

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows. Unfortunately, from your showing script, I cannot understand the values of `user_config` and `i`. And, in your script, `section` is not used. So, I modified your showing script by using a sample values of `ar = [{"section": "Section A", "placeholder": "placeholder"}, {"section": "Section B", "placeholder": "placeholder"}]`. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Modified script:

```py
doc_id = "###" # Please set your Document ID.

# This is a sample value.
ar = [
    {"section": "Section A", "placeholder": "placeholder"},
    {"section": "Section B", "placeholder": "placeholder"},
]

requests = []
for e in reversed(ar):
    nextIndex = len(e["section"]) + 2
    requests = [
        *requests,
        {
            "insertText": {
                "text": "{text}\n".format(text=e["section"]),
                "location": {"index": 1},
            }
        },
        {
            "updateParagraphStyle": {
                "range": {"startIndex": 1, "endIndex": 1},
                "paragraphStyle": {"namedStyleType": "HEADING_2"},
                "fields": "namedStyleType,spaceAbove,spaceBelow",
            }
        },
        {
            "insertText": {
                "location": {"index": nextIndex},
                "text": "{text}\n".format(text=e["placeholder"]),
            }
        },
        {
            "updateParagraphStyle": {
                "range": {"startIndex": nextIndex, "endIndex": nextIndex},
                "paragraphStyle": {"namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT"},
                "fields": "namedStyleType,spaceAbove,spaceBelow",
            }
        },
        {
            "createParagraphBullets": {
                "range": {"startIndex": nextIndex, "endIndex": nextIndex},
                "bulletPreset": "BULLET_ARROW_DIAMOND_DISC",
            }
        },
    ]
result = svc.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=doc_id, body={"requests": requests}).execute()
```

- **About `"namedStyleType": "HEADING_2"`, `"fields": "namedStyleType,spaceAbove,spaceBelow"`, and `"bulletPreset": "BULLET_ARROW_DIAMOND_DISC"` are used from your showing script.**

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateParagraphStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updateparagraphstylerequest)

Comment: Thanks for the example. I tried it out but I'm encountering some "invalid value" errors for the H2 style.  I've created a couple of Gists to show where I'm at for the function (https://gist.github.com/cbellini/443fe3dbe006a3ef95a89f8d0ce2588e) and the config's structure (https://gist.github.com/cbellini/69ead2129d5e568b1d727d38b302c2ef).

Comment: I was adding a new line after the paragraph style ‍♂️

It works now!  I'll see about adding a special case where 1 of the sections also has a sub-section with H3s and each have their own placeholder list as well.